# Why does my code not produce any output?

Tags: java, eclipse

```java
package penny_pinch_v2;

public class Board {

  public static String[] board = new String[25];

  public static void fillBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
      board[i] = "[    ]";
    }
  }
  public static void printBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
      if (i == 5 || i == 10 || i == 15 || i == 20)
        System.out.println();
      System.out.format("%12s", board[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

```java
package penny_pinch_v2;

import java.util.Random;

public class Pennies {

  private static Random random;

  public static void throwPennies() {
    int count, randInt;
    random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      randInt = random.nextInt(25);
      count = 0;
      while (count == 0) {
        if (Board.board[randInt].charAt(1) != '[') {
          Board.board[randInt] = "[" + Board.board[randInt] + "]";
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```java
package penny_pinch_v2;

import java.util.Random;

public class Prizes {

  private static Random random;
  public static String[] prizes = {
    "Puzzle", "Poster", "Ball", "Game", "Doll"
  };
  public static int[] prizeCount = new int[5];

  public static void fillPrizes() {
    int count, randInt;
    random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        count = 0;
        while (count == 0) {
          randInt = random.nextInt(25);
          if (Board.board[randInt] == "[    ]") {
            Board.board[randInt] = "[" + prizes[j] + "]";
            count++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  public static void checkPrizes() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
      if (Board.board[i].equals("[[Puzzle]]"))
        prizeCount[0] ++;
      else if (Board.board[i].equals("[[Poster]]"))
        prizeCount[1] ++;
      else if (Board.board[i].equals("[[Bass]]"))
        prizeCount[2] ++;
      else if (Board.board[i].equals("[[Game]]"))
        prizeCount[3] ++;
      else if (Board.board[i].equals("[[Doll]]"))
        prizeCount[4] ++;
    }
  }

}
```

```java
package penny_pinch_v2;

public class RunPennyPinch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Board.fillBoard();
    Prizes.fillPrizes();
    Pennies.throwPennies();
    Board.printBoard();
    Prizes.checkPrizes();

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      if (Prizes.prizeCount[j] == 3) {
        System.out.println("You won a " + Prizes.prizes[j] + "!");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hey there, I have what I thought to be a working code, but I have recently had problems getting the console to display anything.  Before I added the checkPrizes() method, everything was perfectly fine.  The next day I tried running it and Eclipse would stop responding for a few seconds and nothing would appear in the console.  If anyone could clarify what is wrong, (any logic errors, infinite loops, or Eclipse itself), that would be awesome.  Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried to debug this in Eclipse?

Comment: Java and Javascript are completely different languages

Comment: It's really weird, I tried debugging and it displayed the proper output, but that was only the first time, after that it went back to not responding...

Comment: I think now is the perfect time to learn to use the debugger. Put some breakpoints in your code and step through it.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you might wanna reconsider where you want to increment `count` in `throwPennies` method or maybe a condition which breaks this `while` loop. I modified it as below.

```
while (count == 0) {
      System.out.println("inside throw pennies while");
    if (Board.board[randInt].charAt(1) != '[') {
                  System.out.println("inside throw pennies if");
      Board.board[randInt] = "[" + Board.board[randInt] + "]";

    }
    count++;
  }
```

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Sorry, but no.  The problem seems to lie in checkPrizes(),  As the code will run when no prizes are won.

Answer (score -1):

Can you  try removing the checkPrizes() and run it again. Probably it will give some better understanding .  or may be you can try executing through CLI . which can clear out if problem is with eclipse.